# Отправить POST запрос с помощью PHP

Tags: php, post

нужно на данный URL `https://streaming.vk.com/rules?key=abc` отправить POST запрос `{"rule":{"value":"VALUE","tag":"TAG"}}`. Без использований `<form>` (html), как это сделать?

Comment: используйте curl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если доступно расширение **php-curl**, можно отправить запрос так

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://httpbin.org/post');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"rule":{"value":"VALUE","tag":"TAG"}}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
$out = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $out;
```

Comment: а разве на второй строчке не URL указан...

Comment: не работает для локального php файла. Как с ними быть?

Comment: @ЮрийЖаворонков, не совсем понятен ваш вопрос. Правильно ли я думаю, что у вас есть какой-то JSON файл, содержимое которого нужно отправить напрямую без всяких форм?