# Отправка header методом POST PHP (замена xhr.setRequestHeader)

Tags: php, javascript, http, post

Можно ли как то перевести это в PHP, если да то подскажите пожалуйста как?

```
 function request(func, params, onSuccess) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://FF2:7000/$gate/request', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("pro-verba-esb-queue", "IM");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("x-function", encodeURI(func));
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState != 4) return;
      if (this.status != 200) {
        alert( 'ошибка: ' + (this.status ? this.statusText : 'запрос не удался') );
        return;
      }
      onSuccess(this.responseText);
    }
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
  }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отправить POST запрос PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706453/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-post-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь `curl`

```
$url = 'http://FF2:7000/$gate/request';

$headers = array(
    'pro-verba-esb-queue: IM', 
    'x-function: '+encodeURI(func)
);   

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($params));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

Comment: Спасибо, вот только она мне в ответ говорит:
Ошибка при вызове метода контекста (ПрочитатьJSON)

Хз что не нравится

Answer (score 2):

Используй библиотеку Guzzle. Вот ссылка на нее http://guzzlephp.org. Приведу небольшой пример, а для большего пониманий прочитай документацию

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$client->request('POST', 'http://FF2:7000/$gate/request', [
    'headers' => [
        'pro-verba-esb-queue' => 'IM',
        'x-function'     => ""
     ]
]);
```