# как распознать аудио в текст гуглом на php?

Tags: php, google-speech-recognition

Пробую демо код с главной страницы
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/
таким образом:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=myKey');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"audio":{"content":"RTovT1NQYW5lbC9kb21haW5zL3Rlc2R0L3ZpZGVvcy9nZGdkcy5mbGFj"},"config":{"enableAutomaticPunctuation":true,"encoding":"FLAC","sampleRateHertz":16000,"languageCode":"ru-RU","model":"default"}}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
$out = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $out;
?>
```

В ответ получаю {}

php код для post запроса [тупо скопировал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706453/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-post-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-php)

как получить текст расшифровки?

Answer (score 0):

"content":"тут должен быть ВЕСЬ АУДИО ФАЙЛ в кодировке base64"